# Converting Vector (.shp) to Raster (.tiff) using Python GDAL library

Tags: raster, pyqgis, gdal, vector, rasterization

I'm trying to convert a vector shapefile to a raster tiff file. I adapted the source code from [Python Geospatial Analysis Cookbook by Michael Diener](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-geospatial-analysis/9781783555079/). The code works for line and polygon shapefiles but shows only a black screen for point shapefiles.

```
def main(shapefile):

#making the shapefile as an object.
input_shp = ogr.Open(shapefile)

#getting layer information of shapefile.
shp_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()

#pixel_size determines the size of the new raster.
#pixel_size is proportional to size of shapefile.
pixel_size = 0.1

#get extent values to set size of output raster.
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = shp_layer.GetExtent()

#calculate size/resolution of the raster.
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

#get GeoTiff driver by 
image_type = 'GTiff'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(image_type)

#passing the filename, x and y direction resolution, no. of bands, new raster.
new_raster = driver.Create(output_raster, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

#transforms between pixel raster space to projection coordinate space.
new_raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_size))

#get required raster band.
band = new_raster.GetRasterBand(1)

#assign no data value to empty cells.
no_data_value = -9999
band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
band.FlushCache()

#main conversion method
gdal.RasterizeLayer(new_raster, [1], shp_layer, burn_values=[255])

#adding a spatial reference
new_rasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
new_rasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(2975)
new_raster.SetProjection(new_rasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
return gdal.Open(output_raster)
```

So, my problem is:

What do I change in the code so that it works for point shapefiles too? and how do I get my final output raster file to be of the same color as the input vector file?

The things that do work in the code is:
1. getting input and returning the output properly.
2. getting the proper size/resolution and creating a raster of the required resolution.
3. proper shapes in the output for polygon and line shapefiles.

Comment: Buffer the points by half a pixel or so, it's a bit of a hack but if you're not too fussy it will get you past this roadblock. As for getting the color is it an RGB value or a single int8 (byte)?  as you raster with 1 band only is of type gdal.GDT_Byte, you'd need to make 3 bands and perform 3 burns to implement RGB.

Comment: @MichaelStimson by buffer the points do you mean decrease the pixel size? because if so, then I already decreased it from 1 to 0.1 and it still doesn't work. (i'm a complete newbie to gis with python so sorry for the trouble)

Comment: @MichaelStimson also how do i make 3 bands and perform 3 burns? do I just input 3 as the number of bands and put burn values = [255,255,255]? or is there a different way?

Comment: I suppose that rasterizing a point will give you only one colored pixel. Turning points into round polygons with buffer makes rasterized features more visible. If your aim is to get a good looking map you should probably use other tools for rendering. You can also test how the function works with the ready made utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html.

Comment: @user30184 can you explain how do I turn the points into round polygons with buffer?

Comment: See "buffer a geometry" from https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html.